# Rock paper scissors code not consistently printing outcome

Tags: python

This is the code that I wrote for a very basic rock paper scissors game.
However when I run the code. It doesn't always print the outcome of the game, ie. You win!, You lose or tie. I am not quite sure why this is the case. HELP!![1]

`

```
start_game = input('Type start to start game:').lower()
import random
def play():
    user = input("'rock' , 'paper', 'scissors' ").lower()
    if user == 'quit':
        print("Game ended :(")
        exit()
    computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper','scissors'])
    print(computer)
    if user == computer:
        return 'tie'
    elif not user == is_win(user, computer):
        return 'You win!'
    else:
        return 'You lost!'

def is_win(player,opponent):
    if (player == 'rock'and opponent == 'scissors') or (player == 'scissors'and opponent == 'paper') or \
            (player=='paper' and opponent == 'rock'):
        return True
    print(play())

while True:
    if start_game != 'start':
        start_game = input('Sorry i dont understand please try again:')
    else:
        print(play())
```

output:
Type start to start game:srt
Sorry i dont understand please try again:start
'rock' , 'paper', 'scissors' rock
paper

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic to decide the winner is slightly wrong. The object `user` just contains the user's choice. The function `is_win` should return a boolean. You do return `True` when the user wins, but when he loses, you're recalling the original calling function.

```
start_game = input('Type start to start game:').lower()
import random
def play():
    user = input("'rock' , 'paper', 'scissors' ").lower()
    if user == 'quit':
        print("Game ended :(")
        exit()
    computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper','scissors'])
    print(computer)
    if user == computer:
        return 'tie'
    elif is_win(user, computer):
        return 'You win!'
    else:
        return 'You lost!'

def is_win(player,opponent):
    if (player == 'rock'and opponent == 'scissors') or (player == 'scissors'and opponent == 'paper') or \
            (player=='paper' and opponent == 'rock'):
        return True
    return False

while True:
    if start_game != 'start':
        start_game = input('Sorry i dont understand please try again:')
    else:
        print(play())
```

Try making the above changes and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just would like to know why I do not need an else: statement before the return False?

Comment: @Harini Because if the 'if' statement be true, then the function will return and the rest of the function will not be executed. so having an "else" will not make any difference

Answer (score 0):

You are using is_win() function before defining it!

define the function before play function!

consider this

```
start_game = input('Type start to start game:').lower()
import random

def is_win(player,opponent):
    if (player == 'rock'and opponent == 'scissors') or (player == 'scissors'and opponent == 'paper') or \
            (player=='paper' and opponent == 'rock'):
        return True
    print(play())

def play():
    user = input("'rock' , 'paper', 'scissors' ").lower()
    if user == 'quit':
        print("Game ended :(")
        exit()
    computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper','scissors'])
    print(computer)
    if user == computer:
        return 'tie'
    elif not user == is_win(user, computer):
        return 'You win!'
    else:
        return 'You lost!'


while True:
    if start_game != 'start':
        start_game = input('Sorry i dont understand please try again:')
    else:
        print(play())
```

Comment: This is not a problem. They are calling the function "is_win" inside another function. Both functions are defined and can be used when the compiler gets to the "while True".

Answer (score 0):

what is that `print(play())` for? You are running another round of the game inside an unfinished round. I think you should return False instead of that and also change the 'elif' condition:

```
start_game = input('Type start to start game:').lower()
import random
def play():
    user = input("'rock' , 'paper', 'scissors' ").lower()
    if user == 'quit':
        print("Game ended :(")
        exit()
    computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper','scissors'])
    print(computer)
    if user == computer:
        return 'tie'
    elif is_win(user, computer):
        return 'You win!'
    else:
        return 'You lost!'

def is_win(player,opponent):
    if (player == 'rock'and opponent == 'scissors') or (player == 'scissors'and opponent == 'paper') or \
            (player=='paper' and opponent == 'rock'):
        return True
    return False

while True:
    if start_game != 'start':
        start_game = input('Sorry i dont understand please try again:')
    else:
        print(play())
```